# Extract key value from free text using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

Let's say I have this free text

```
unitType:unit_failure;unitId:b7eb;unitTitle:L1-O VEN_ACC_SETTINGS>(30s)>EXCL(A);applicable:true;comment:Decline sender:SELLER;Decline reason:VEN_ACC_SETTINGS;triggered by user:495259708;Display reason: CON_FAILURE;modified by: log_res_mon
```

I want to extract the values into an object that has the same property names.

```
public class Values
{
    public string UnitType { get; set; }
    public string UnitId { get; set; }
    public string UnitTitle { get; set; }
    public string Applicable { get; set; }
    public string DeclineSender { get; set; }
    public string DeclineReason { get; set; }
    public string TriggeredByUser { get; set; }
    public string DisplayReason { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

so far I tried this code:

```
    string comment = "unitType:unit_failure;unitId:b7eb;unitTitle:L1-O VEN_ACC_SETTINGS>(30s)>EXCL(A);applicable:true;comment:Decline sender:SELLER;Decline reason:VEN_ACC_SETTINGS;triggered by user:495259708;Display reason: CON_FAILURE;modified by: log_res_mon";
    string regex = @"(.*?:\s*)(\w*);?";

    var matches = Regex.Matches(comment, regex);
```

Which almost worked. but you can see that `unitTitle` was cut after `L1-`.

Another thing, `comment:` is an exception that can be dropped either by the expression, or I can simply drop it using `.Replace`.

[image]

- How do I fix the expression to include the full value of `unitTitle` and to drop `comment:` (You can tell me it is easier to use `.Replace`)?
- What is the best way to extract the values from `matches` and fill them in the object?

EDIT:
I tried this, but it is really ugly, is there a better way? (Ignore that I'm using anonymous object, that is just for testing now).

```
    var obj = new
    {
        unitType = matches.Single(x => x.Groups[1].Value == "unitType").Groups[2].Value
    };
```

EDIT: A lot of good answers, but I can only choose one so I choose the one with the simple Regex query.

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I think it is obvious that the image is from VS Code that shows values at run time and no way to copy-paste them as is. 
Plus the image was meant only to explain how the issue happen (the value is broken down into two fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regex pattern

```
(?<name>(\w|\s)+):\s*(?<value>[^;]*);?
```

I have used named groups, so that it is easily possible to extract the variable name and the value.

```cs
var comment = @"unitType:unit_failure;unitId:b7eb;unitTitle:L1-O VEN_ACC_SETTINGS>(30s)>EXCL(A);applicable:true;comment:Decline sender:SELLER;Decline reason:VEN_ACC_SETTINGS;triggered by user:495259708;Display reason: CON_FAILURE;modified by: log_res_mon";
var pattern = @"(?<name>(\w|\s)+):\s*(?<value>[^;]*);?";

// Add ";" before "Decline sender:" to place "comment:" into another match.
comment = comment.Replace("Decline sender:", ";Decline sender:");

Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);       
var matches = regex.Matches(comment);
foreach (Match m in matches) {
    string name = m.Groups["name"].Value;
    string value = m.Groups["value"].Value;

    Console.WriteLine($"{name}={value}");
}
```

Yields:

```
unitType=unit_failure
unitId=b7eb
unitTitle=L1-O VEN_ACC_SETTINGS>(30s)>EXCL(A)
applicable=true
comment=
Decline sender=SELLER
Decline reason=VEN_ACC_SETTINGS
triggered by user=495259708
Display reason=CON_FAILURE
modified by=log_res_mon
```

If `comment:` is always empty, then `comment = comment.Replace(";comment:", ";");` will remove it. If, however, the comment can have a value, I would replace `"Decline sender:"` by `";Decline sender:"`. This puts the comment into another match.

See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PROf3F

Explanation of `(?<name>(\w|\s)+):\s*(?<value>[^;]*);?`:

- `(?<name>expression)` is a named group.
- `(\w|\s)+` expression of named group "name". One or more word characters or whitespaces.
- `:\s*` a colon and optional spaces between the variable name and the value.
- `[^;]*` expression of named group "value". Any number of characters except `;`.
- `;?` an optional semicolon.

You can easily put the values into an object with

```cs
var values = new Values(); // Create object before the foreach-loop.

// In the matches loop:
switch (name) {
    "unitType":
        values.UnitType = value;
        break;
    "unitId":
        values.UnitId = value;
        break;
    ...
}
```

Or add name/value pairs to a `Dictionary<string,string>` with `dict[name] = value;` to enable an easy lookup of the value by name.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the simple Regex query, I chose a slightly different approach with the code though.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if `comment:`  shoudl always be removed and it's always like this, you don't need Regex at all, you can split by `;` then by `:`:

```
string input = @"unitType:unit_failure;unitId:b7eb;unitTitle:L1-O VEN_ACC_SETTINGS>(30s)>EXCL(A);applicable:true;comment:Decline sender:SELLER;Decline reason:VEN_ACC_SETTINGS;triggered by user:495259708;Display reason: CON_FAILURE;modified by: log_res_mon";
var fields = input.Replace("comment:","")
    .Split(';')
    .Select(x => x.Split(':', 2))
    .ToDictionary(x => x[0],x => x[1]);

Values values = new Values
{
    UnitType = fields["unitType"],
    UnitId = fields["unitId"],
    UnitTitle = fields["unitTitle"],
    Applicable = fields["applicable"],
    DeclineSender = fields["Decline sender"],
    DeclineReason = fields["Decline reason"],
    TriggeredByUser = fields["triggered by user"],
    DisplayReason = fields["Display reason"],
    ModifiedBy = fields["modified by"]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```cs
\b(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*):\s*(.*?)(?=\s*;\w+(?:\s+\w+)*:|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XCPAhL/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)` - Group 1: one or more word chars followed with zero or more occurrences of one or more whitespaces and one or more word chars
- `:` - a colon
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
- `(.*?)` - Group 2:
- `(?=\s*;\w+(?:\s+\w+)*:|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires its pattern to match immediately to the right of the current location:

  - `\s*;\w+(?:\s+\w+)*:` - zero or more whitespaces, `;` and then one or more word chars followed with zero or more occurrences of one or more whitespaces and one or more word chars
  - `|` - or
  - `$` - end of string.

See  the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/dZ5Ok1):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public class Values
    {
        public string UnitType { get; set; }
        public string UnitId { get; set; }
        public string UnitTitle { get; set; }
        public string Applicable { get; set; }
        public string DeclineSender { get; set; }
        public string DeclineReason { get; set; }
        public string TriggeredByUser { get; set; }
        public string DisplayReason { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        
        public override string ToString() 
        {
            return $"UnitType: {UnitType}\nUnitId: {UnitId}\nUnitTitle: {UnitTitle}\nApplicable: {Applicable}\nDeclineSender: {DeclineSender}\nDeclineReason: {DeclineReason}\nTriggeredByUser: {TriggeredByUser}\nDisplayReason: {DisplayReason}\nModifiedBy: {ModifiedBy}";
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        var pattern = @"\b(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*):\s*(.*?)(?=\s*;\w+(?:\s+\w+)*:|$)";
        var text = "unitType:unit_failure;unitId:b7eb;unitTitle:L1-O VEN_ACC_SETTINGS>(30s)>EXCL(A);applicable:true;comment:Decline sender:SELLER;Decline reason:VEN_ACC_SETTINGS;triggered by user:495259708;Display reason: CON_FAILURE;modified by: log_res_mon";
        text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<![^;])comment:(?=(?:unitType|unitId|unitTitle|applicable|Decline sender|Decline reason|triggered by user|Display reason|modified by):)", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var vals = new List<Values>();
        var v = new Values();
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(text, pattern))
        {
            if (m.Groups[1].Value == "unitType") v.UnitType=m.Groups[2].Value;
            if (m.Groups[1].Value == "unitId") v.UnitId=m.Groups[2].Value;
            if (m.Groups[1].Value == "unitTitle") v.UnitTitle=m.Groups[2].Value;
            if (m.Groups[1].Value == "applicable") v.Applicable=m.Groups[2].Value;
            if (m.Groups[1].Value == "Decline sender") v.DeclineSender=m.Groups[2].Value;
            if (m.Groups[1].Value == "Decline reason") v.DeclineReason=m.Groups[2].Value;
            if (m.Groups[1].Value == "triggered by user") v.TriggeredByUser=m.Groups[2].Value;
            if (m.Groups[1].Value == "Display reason") v.DisplayReason=m.Groups[2].Value;
            if (m.Groups[1].Value == "modified by") v.ModifiedBy=m.Groups[2].Value;
            
        }
        Console.WriteLine(v.ToString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
UnitType: unit_failure
UnitId: b7eb
UnitTitle: L1-O VEN_ACC_SETTINGS>(30s)>EXCL(A)
Applicable: true
DeclineSender: SELLER
DeclineReason: VEN_ACC_SETTINGS
TriggeredByUser: 495259708
DisplayReason: CON_FAILURE
ModifiedBy: log_res_mon
```

Comment: Ok, how did you do that! 

Comment: @Nour Wait, why is there no `;` for the empty *comment* value in `comment:Decline sender:SELLER;`? Shouldn't the input be like here, https://regex101.com/r/XCPAhL/2?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I mentioned that 'comment:' is an exception and need to be dropped from the text. Don't worry, I will use .Replace to remove it anyway.

Comment: @Nour All is now fixed. Do you need case insensitive matching?

Answer (score 0):

You might also exclude matching `;` and `:` for the property name, and exclude matching `;` as the property value.

```
([^:;]+):\s*([^;]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lpz6D9/1)

Or if there has to be at least a word character for the key and the value, and not capturing `comment:`

```
\bcomment:\s*[^;\w]*\w[^;]*|([^:;\w]*\w[^:;]*):\s*([^;\w]*\w[^;]*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bcomment:\s*[^;\w]*\w[^;]*` Match comment that you don't want
- `|` or
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^:;\w]*` Optionally match any char except `:` `;` or a word char
  - `\w` Match a single word char
  - `[^:;]*` Optionally repeat matching any char except `:` and `;`
- `)` , match at least a word char
- `:\s*` Match `:` and optional whitespace chars
- `([^;\w]*\w[^;]*)` Capture **group 2** Same approach as group 1 only excluding `;`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7qeF0d/1)

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks, would you mind answering the second question?
I will edit the question to add an example code I used, but it is ugly.

Comment: @Nour The pattern does not have named capture groups, so you can check the group 1 value to get the accompanying value for that property. Is the string always in that order, and are the properties always there?

Comment: They are in that order, but not guaranteed, I don't want to count on that, it is from an external source that I have no control over. I will check how to name the groups if finding it would be easier than counting on the number.

Answer (score 0):

My approach also favors Split, ToDictionary over RegEx, for this use case.
And assinging the values "by name" using Reflection.

```
var str = "unitType:unit_failure;unitId:b7eb;unitTitle:L1-O VEN_ACC_SETTINGS>(30s)>EXCL(A);applicable:true;comment:Decline sender:SELLER;Decline reason:VEN_ACC_SETTINGS;triggered by user:495259708;Display reason: CON_FAILURE;modified by: log_res_mon";

        var nameValueMap = str.Replace("comment:", "")
                     .Split(";")
                     .Select(token => token.Split(":"))
                     .ToDictionary(arr => arr[0].Replace(" ", "").Trim(), 
                                   arr => arr[1].Trim());

        var instance = new Values();
        var type     = instance.GetType();
        foreach (var kv in nameValueMap) {
            type.InvokeMember(
                               kv.Key,
                               BindingFlags.Instance
                             | BindingFlags.SetProperty
                             | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase
                             | BindingFlags.Public,
                               null,
                               instance,
                               new object[] { kv.Value }
                              );
        }
```

Result:
[image: Values in "instance":]